# Centrar dt/dd verticalmente en Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Les comento, estoy trabajando con Bootstrap 4, y estoy teniendo un problema al querer centrar verticalmente los `dd` dentro de un `dl`

Mi código sería algo así

```css
    dl {
        display: flex !important;
        justify-content: center !important;
        align-items: center !important;
    }
    dd{
        vertical-align: middle !important;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
    <dl class="row mt-2 border border-dark rounded">
        
        <dt class="col-2">Prueba</dt>
        <dd class="col">07-B0COA</dd>

        <dt class="col-2">Cliente</dt>
        <dd class="col">EDE</dd>

    </dl>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Logré centrar los `dt` sin problema con el css que aplico a `dl`, pero no logro que los `dd` se centren de la misma manera.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Por defecto b4, aplica un `margin-bottom: .5rem;` a los elementos `dd`. podría ser la razón.

Comment: @Dev.Joel efectivamente, no lo había notado! muchísimas gracias, por ahí estuvo la solución!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema como comenté, es debido al margen que b4 aplica a los elementos `dd` , podría remover este margen para evitar ese fallo.

Además no es necesario de más `css`, si ya tiene `b4` y clases que pueden ayudarle. `align-items-center` par centrar el contenido y  `mb-0` , para eliminar el `margin-bottom: .5rem;`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<div class="container">
    <dl class="row mt-2 border border-dark rounded align-items-center" style="height: 300px"  >
        
        <dt class="col-2 ">Prueba</dt>
        <dd class="col mb-0 ">07-B0COA</dd>

        <dt class="col-2 ">Cliente</dt>
        <dd class="col mb-0 ">EDE</dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```